# Shiny DT datatable to Rmarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, dt

I have a shiny dashboard app that shows a DT datatable.  The raw data is manipulated in a function based on user inputs on the sidebar.  All is good and working well.

My question is how do I get the data table to render in an Rmarkdown html page.  Nothing I've tried works.

Here is some simple code by way of an example.  I wish the table to render in an Rmarkdown page when I click a download button.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
data(iris)

ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("|Species Table"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         selectInput("specs",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     unique(iris$Species))
      ),

      mainPanel(
         tableOutput("specTable")
      )
   )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  subSpec <- function(x){
    iris[iris$Species == x, -5]
    iris[1:10,]
  }

  reactiveFunction <- reactive({ subSpec(input$specs) })

  output$reactiveTable <- renderDataTable({ reactiveFunction() }, rownames = FALSE)

  output$specTable <- renderUI({
    dataTableOutput("reactiveTable")
  })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So in this example, how would I pass dataTableOutput("reactiveTable") to Rmarkdown?

Thanks

Comment: You can pass the data frame to RMarkdown by rendering an RMD file using the data:  https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html

Comment: Thanks.  I did look at that before but without luck. in the app I have about 20 tables each with their own functions sourced from their own directories and I didn't want to repeat a lot of code loading the data and sourcing the functions in Rmarkdown.  I basically wanted the app to do the work and just pass the final tables in Rmarkdown.

Comment: You can pass the final table as a data frame, but you'll have to render the Rmd file - no getting around that. Other option is to add download buttons for the tables: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for you, you need to use `downloadHandler()` argument in shiny app at first:

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
data(iris)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("|Species Table"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("specs",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  unique(iris$Species)),
      downloadButton('downloadReport')
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("specTable")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  subSpec <- function(x){
    iris[iris$Species == x, -5]
    iris[1:10,]
  }

  reactiveFunction <- reactive({ subSpec(input$specs) })

  output$reactiveTable <- renderDataTable({ reactiveFunction() }, rownames = FALSE)

  output$specTable <- renderUI({
    dataTableOutput("reactiveTable")
  })


  output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("test",".html",sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      src <- normalizePath('report_file.Rmd')

      # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
      # permission to the current working directory
      owd <- setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      file.copy(src, 'report_file.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE) 

      out <- rmarkdown::render('report_file.Rmd')
      file.rename(out, file)
    }
  )

}




shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and additionally you need report_file.Rmd file in the same directory as app.R file where `DT` is going to render:

**report_file.Rmd**

````
```{r, fig.align='center', fig.pos='htb!', echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, tidy=TRUE}
library(DT)
datatable(reactiveFunction(),rownames=FALSE, options = list(dom='t',ordering=F))
```
````

Comment: Thanks, But how does this pass the function to Rmd?  You do not list the parameters?

Comment: Well you just need to use / paste the name of the reactive data/function in your case `reactiveFunction()` which you have created in shiny and it is going to work. No you do not need to list the parameters (as long as it is not the plot which has been created in shiny and should be implemented in Rmarkdown)