# Converting DT::datatable from shiny to Rmarkdown PDF

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, r-markdown

This question is related to these questions:

1- [Shiny DT datatable to Rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844673/shiny-dt-datatable-to-rmarkdown)
2- [render DT::datatables in a pdf using rmarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55845388/render-dtdatatables-in-a-pdf-using-rmarkdown)
3- [how to render DT::datatables in a pdf using rmarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44543858/how-to-render-dtdatatables-in-a-pdf-using-rmarkdown)

As the phantomjs is not going to be updated anymore, I was wondering if there is any other way beside webshot method to render DT::datatable usedin Shiny app into a pdf using rmarkdown

Here is a simple Rmarkdown code:

````
---
title: "DT"
output: pdf_document
---

### Chart 1
```{r}
DT::datatable(head(mtcars))
```
````